# Powershell - MailboxFolderPermissions problem with multiple Exchange Servers

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-remoting

I've been trying to solve this problem for days and at least narrowed it down. I'm writing a script for my company with a user interface that allows my colleagues to easily create a new Active Directory user based on a template user, create a new mailbox and add Calendar permissions to their Manager.

Everything is working except for adding the Calendar permissions.

We are running two Exchange Servers, let's call them Exchange1 and Exchange2. Enabling the mailbox based on the AD user works fine but when I get to the step of adding calendar permissions I get this error:

```
The mailbox /o=COMPANY/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=EXCHANGE2/cn=Microsoft System 
Attendant kann nicht geöffnet werden.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-MailboxFolderPermission], MailboxUnavailableException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=EXCHANGE1,RequestId=4f818454-7ffc-4fd9-b57d-594bedd7fab6,TimeStamp=15.10.2020 14:11:32] [FailureCategory=Cmd 
   let-MailboxUnavailableException] 676ABDB0,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.AddMailboxFolderPermission
    + PSComputerName        : EXCHANGE1
```

The command I'm trying to run:

```
Enable-Mailbox -Identity $ADUser

$EmailCalendar = $Email + ":\Calendar"

Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $EmailCalendar -User $Manager -AccessRights Editor
```

I'm really new to using Powershell administrating Exchange servers, so I'm kind of at my troubleshooting end. It doesn't matter if I connect to EXCHANGE1 or EXCHANGE2, the error message stays the same and I'm having trouble understand why the mailbox is unavailable.

Any help is appreciate:)

Comment: Show the commands you are running that cause the error.

Comment: I'm connecting to Exchange2 with New-PSSession, then enabling the Mailbox of a previously created AD User which works fine - then I'm trying to run:

Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity EmailOfUser\:Calendar -User $TargetEmail -AccessRights Editor

Comment: I added the few commands at the top post.